# Mongo DB collection size not changed after removal of fields from document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

To reduce my existing collection size, I have removed some unwanted fields from the documents from the collection. After and before I ran the collection stats to check the size, but it never changed.
I am missing some thing (like update anything) to reflect the reduced size in my stats, Please advice me.
I am running this in my local PC, not having any other nodes.
Thank you.

Comment: 2021-06: `db.runCommand({ compact: "collection-name" })` https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/compact/

Answer (score 5):

This is correct behavior.
The only time mongo releases disk space is when you drop a database or do a repair. [(see here)](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2838)

prettier explanation [here](http://blog.mongolab.com/2014/01/managing-disk-space-in-mongodb/)

Basically, mongodb keeps any space it has allocated unless and until you drop a database or do a repair. It does this because adding space is not efficient, it is time-consuming. So once it has it, it keeps it and uses the blank space created until there is none left and then it gets more.

Comment: If you are using a replica set, you can actually reset one node of your set and it will pull all the data in its startup sync from the other nodes. The footprint of the data will be smaller at that point than it ever will be after that. You can then see the total space your database actually needs. Also, this is a handy way to reclaim space because you can sync your nodes this way one at a time to reduce space without causing your replica set to go offline.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Daniel F in a comment on the question, this worked for me in the mongo shell:

```
use your-database-name
db.runCommand({ compact: "your-collection-name" })
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I'll add that here just in case. Read carefully the documentation on **compact** as it causes the node it is run on to stop taking most of the traffic until it is done.
All previous ideas have their usecases I'll add another one that might be the best fit. If your able to query the subset that you want to leave from the collection and it is a lot smaller than the entire collection and you have tons of other collections there that you don't want to wait on restoring from scratch then you can write the sub query to another collection, apply indexes and when done plan a short downtime if necessary and switch the collections.

Comment: Starting in v4.4, compact does not block MongoDB CRUD Operations on the database it is compacting.